# Format array to display every alternate in the multidimensional array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

here is my array

```
a = [["A", "B"], ["323", "32"]]
```

Now what I want to be able to is format this array in such a way that it shows

```
A = 323
B = 32
```

How do i do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `Array#transpose`, I believe:

```
> a = [["A", "B"], ["323", "32"]]
=> [["A", "B"], ["323", "32"]]
>> a.transpose
=> [["A", "323"], ["B", "32"]]
```

Comment: wow. That made it so easy than I was thinking. thanks so much :)

Comment: Just in case this helps: `Hash[a.transpose] # => {"A"=>"323", "B"=>"32"}` +1

Comment: @Kyle Good tip. Makes direct access much easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
(0...a.first.length).each{|i| puts "#{a[0][i]} = #{a[1][i]}"}
```